# Bash Syntax error near new line on iOS

Tags: ios, bash, unix, apt-get

So I have a script (the code is below) and I am getting the following error.

**Error:**

```
Syntax error near unexpected token newline (line 5)
```

The code around this error is

```
Sbalert -t "Updating" -m "Downloading and installing the update. Please don't touch your device until it reboots" -d "" & 
alert_id="$!"
apt-get install --only-upgrade <Whited00r 7.1 OTA>
reboot
```

This has been made for an iPod using bash so it may be different to the ones on desktop... And if there is another way to update a specific package that would be nice as well...

Comment: Stack Overflow's syntax highlighting has potentially answered your question: it looks like you are missing a closing double quote after `"string2`.

Comment: That's the entire script... Just without the shebang I'll edit it to reflect the code more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this line:

```
apt-get install --only-upgrade <Whited00r 7.1 OTA>
```

The `<` and `>` characters are special to the shell.  They tell it to perform input and output redirection.  The shell expects a filename after each.  Since you put `>` at the end of the line, the shell is complaining.

If the package is named `Whited00r 7.1 OTA`, then you need to run this command:

```
apt-get install --only-upgrade "Whited00r 7.1 OTA"
```

However, I have no idea if that is actually the name of a package you can install.

Comment: that was a typo.. Updated the code to fix it. Sorry about that.

Comment: @itechy21 This is the correct answer. The `<Whited00r 7.1 OTA>` part of that line is incorrect. What is the name of the package you are trying to install?

Comment: I used [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/44122/how-to-upgrade-a-single-package-using-apt-get) to get information for what to use

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It is the right package as it is called Whited00r 7.1 OTA and its done on iOS via cydia but using apt-get I have cut out the slowness cydia does to the old idevices...